# Mock Postman request using axios is returning string instead of object

Tags: axios, mocking, postman, postman-mocks

I have created a Postman mock server. I am calling the server in my web application using `axios` as below:

```
const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/products`, {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
const axiosData = response.data;
return axiosData.data;
```

Weirdly `axiosData` is a string! Therefore `axiosData.data` which contains the actual data from the response is `undefined`.

How can I get my Postman mock server to return `axiosData` as `JSON`?

Note: I have also set a response header: `Content-type: application/json` for my response in Postman.

Edit:

This is the response I get back from the mock server (which is `string`):
[image]

Comment: What data you get when calling in chrome

Comment: And in postman , please add screenshot of mock server response

Comment: @PDHide I added a screenshot of the mock server response in the question. It's basically looking like a JSON but it's a string.

Comment: @PDHide I found the problem, the JSON was constructed wrongly on Postman itself. I had an extra line for `product_description` which broke the JSON>

Comment: Your string is also not enclosed in double quotes